# How can debug and make excution the Apex Class Action

Tags: salesforce, apex

I would like to execute this apex class in the debug "Open Execute Anonymous Window":

***ExternalDriveUploadQueueAction*** apex class is to queue an upload request to the external google drive.

Code is as below:

```
public with sharing class ExternalDriveUploadQueueAction {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Queue an External Drive File Upload' description='Creates a record in the External Drive Upload and schedules its execution')

    public static void execute (List<Request> requests) {

        ExternalDriveUploadQueueService service = new ExternalDriveUploadQueueService();
        List<ExternalDriveUploadQueueService.FileURLQueueRequest> queueRequests = new List<ExternalDriveUploadQueueService.FileURLQueueRequest>();
        service.load();
        for (Request request : requests) {
            ExternalDriveUploadQueueService.FileURLQueueRequest queueRequest = 
            new ExternalDriveUploadQueueService.FileURLQueueRequest(
                request.fileURL, request.fileName, request.httpSettingsName, 
                request.recordId, request.folderName);
            queueRequests.add(queueRequest);
        }
        service.queue(queueRequests);
    }

    public class Request {
        @InvocableVariable(label='Relative File URL' description='Relative URL to the file to upload' required=true)
        public String fileURL;
        @InvocableVariable(label='File Name' description='Full name of the file to upload' required=true)
        public String fileName;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Http Settings Name' description='HttpSettings developer name to use to upload the file' required=true)
        public String httpSettingsName;
        @InvocableVariable(label='RecordId' description='Id of record whose folder to upload the file' required=true)
        public Id recordId;
        @InvocableVariable(label='Folder Name' description='Name of folder to upload the file. Empty String, AUTO, SUBFOLDER, or name of folder' required=true)
        public String folderName;
        public Request(){}
        public Request(String fileURL, String fileName, String httpSettingsName, Id recordId, String folderName) {
            this.fileURL = fileURL;
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.httpSettingsName = httpSettingsName;
            this.recordId = recordId;
            this.folderName = folderName;
        }
    }
}
```

My execution and calling the ***ExternalDriveUploadQueueAction*** method is as below:

```
List<Request> bizrequest = new List<Request>{'fileURL','fileName','httpsettingName', 'ID', 'foldername'};
ExternalDriveUploadQueueAction.execute(bizrequest);
```

But above execution calling is showing the error like below:

```
Initial expression is of incorrect type, expected: System.Request but was: String
```

I would like to know the called execution method.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an unit test for verifying this class works OK and providing code coverage. It would be a nice example how a fellow developer can use this class in Apex (not just in Flow).

Since "your" request is an inner class (not defined in it's own file) you probably need something like

```apex
List<ExternalDriveUploadQueueAction.Request> requests = new List<ExternalDriveUploadQueueAction.Request>{
    new ExternalDriveUploadQueueAction.Request('fileURL','fileName','httpsettingName', 'ID', 'foldername')
};
ExternalDriveUploadQueueAction.execute(requests);
```